# What's better - Directly using an ajax call or putting it in a function and calling it from multiple places

Tags: ajax

These are the 2 options that both work the same:

```
        var promise=doAjax(dataStr,'shop');
        promise.success(function(data){
            json=eval('('+data+')');
            console.log(json['Data']);
        });
        promise.error(function(data){
            alert('There was an error');
        });
```

With function:

```
function doAjax(dataStr,process){
    return $.ajax({
        data: dataStr,
        url: '/process/'+process+'/'
    });
}
```

Or it otherwise look like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            data: dataStr,
            url: '/process/shop/',
            success: function(data){
                json=eval('('+data+')');
                console.log(json['Data']);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('There was an error');
            }
        });
```

So what is the most efficient way of doing it, as the first method is slightly lighter code?

Comment: Is there a better way to get a javascript array from the json return data than this: success: function(data){ json=eval('('+data+')');}

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your wrapper often, you can implement it for sure to keep your code clean, sometimes i use following wrapper:

```
//initPostData() returns ready-to-post js object
ajaxWrapper(initPostData(), "url", function (response) { 
    //some logic here              
});

function ajaxWrapper(postData, url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        url: url,
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            //error logic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So in your example are you saying that postData is an array which you turn into JSON and send this via the POST?

Comment: it's not an array, in my case it was an object, but definitely could be anything